# laravel 5 mail not received through gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5 & trying to send mail but it did not send the mail i didn't get any error...

my HomeController.php file is:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use View;
use App\User;
use Mail;
class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function home()
    {
        Mail::send('emails.password', array('name' => 'The New Topic'),   function($message){
        $message->to('my-email@gmail.com', 'The New Topic')->subject('Test Email');

    });
    return View::make('home');
}

}
?>
```

& my mail.php file is:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp-mail.gmail.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => ['address' => 'my-email@gmail.com', 'name' => 'The New Topic'],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tsl',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('my-email@gmail.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => env('mypassword'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

];
?>
```

& my .env file is:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=52YpJyToHN6fJTTKvl3xHfKRO1aPiqYo

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=auth
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

please help me where i'm wrong in my code?

Comment: The first thing I noticed is your encryption value is 'tsl'. Needs to be 'tls'.

Comment: Also, your gmail may need to have the less secure apps setting enabled. Enable the “Less secure apps” setting at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps.

Comment: you are using the env function incorrectly, it should refer to the .env file keys not the actual values!

Comment: @fire He is using the env function correctly. The first argument is the key, the second argument is a default value if no key is found. See, for example, the env() function used for APP_KEY: 'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString')

Comment: @lxndr he is using it correctly for the first few values, but if you read a little further down he messed up the username & password,

Comment: i have changed the encryption from 'tsl' to 'tls' & also enabled the less secure apps setting but i'm not getting mail in my inbox of gmail @lxndr

Comment: @Kryten so what is the correct way please can u tell me in  the username & password

Comment: Look at the way you're configuring `host` and `port` in your `mail.php` file - you're referring to the environment variable name in the call to `env()`. Now look at the way you're configuring `username` - you should be referring to the environment variable name not the value when you call `env()`. I don't know if that will solve your problem, but it is an error.

Comment: @Kryten i have changed that but its not working...it is not showing any error but i'm unable to receive the mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com` instead of `MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.gmail.com`.

Comment: Does this answer work ? It seems like the OP fix the post, but not accept the answer. Please keep us all posted and mark your question as solve.